# What can be the regular expression for creating groups based on count of characters?

Tags: regex, sanitization

The string I want to run the expression on will be of these two type:

> 2012-11  ie yyyy-mm
>
> 11-2012  ie mm-yyyy

I want to write a regular expression for constructing the string of format:

> (regular expression group1)-(regular expression group2)

such that the group1 is always the yyyy part and group2 is mm.

I want to write this function to normalize the date format to a single yyyy-mm type.

Can regular expression be used to solve this?

Comment: what have you tried? Please put some piece of code so that it is easy for others to understand

Comment: @Priyanka nothing yet. I can elaborate the problem is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can use lookaheads, you could perhaps use something like this:

```
(?=.*(\b\d{4}\b))(?=.*(\b\d{2}\b)).*
```

And replace by:

```
\1-\2
```

(or `$1-$2`)

See [here](http://www.regex101.com/r/wT4oB8)

Comment: Nice usage of lookaround, +1.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand it. But this is impressive.

Comment: @sul4bh The lookaheads `(?=...)` looks for characters ahead. The first lookahead, `(?=.*(\b\d{4}\b))` looks for a 4 digit number and captures it in the first group: `\1`; `(?=.*(\b\d{2}\b))` looks for a 2 digit number and captures it in the second group: `\2`. The replace by `\1-\2` sorts the captured groups into the format you need :)

Comment: Cool, so the trick is to capture 4 and 2 character group separately using lookaheads. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

Match:  `\b(?:(\d{4})-(\d{2})|(\d{2})-(\d{4}))\b`

Replace: `$1$4-$2$3`

If a group doesn't participate in the match, any reference to that group in the replacement string is treated as an empty string.  So group #1 concatenated with group #4 will always be the year, and group #2 concatenated with group #3 will always be the month.

This assumes you're using your language's regex-replace mechanism, like PHP's `preg_replace()` or Java's `replaceAll()`.  If you use (for example) Java's `group(n)` method, non-participating groups are returned as null values, which get converted to the word `null` when you assign them to a string variable.  So an assignment like

```
String year = m.group(1) + m.group(4);
```

...would result in `2011null` or `null2011`.  Most languages are smarter than that, but it's something you should watch out for.

Comment: This is pretty straight forward and easy to understand. Thanks.